# nl80211: Could not configure driver mode nl80211 driver initialization failed

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux

I am in `kali linux 2.0` from virtual machine of `windows 10` .when I try the command `bash /usr/share/mana-toolkit/run-mana/start-nat-simple.sh`  to run  `start-nat-simple.sh` file the following error is displayed

```
Configuration file: /etc/mana-toolkit/hostapd-mana.conf
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
Hit enter to kill me
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call ifconfig on your Kali Linux, do you see an entry called wlan0 ?

I'm not sure what the start-nat-simple.sh script is doing. If we look in the file, /etc/mana-toolkit/hostapd-mana.conf, cat /etc/mana-toolkit/hostapd-mana.conf, do you see an interface option pointing wlan0. If your WiFi interface has a different name displayed from ifconfig I would try to point the conf file to it, given that there is an interface option.